# Unity 2d: Interactable tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a 2d game with tiles that are interactable, i.e farmland, trees, breakable rocks, etc.

Now if I create my tilemap in Tiled which I have done so far, it does not offer that type of control.

I found some posts on how to deal with this but they are at least 3 years old, so wondering if there is some updated answer? maybe something built in to Unity or a plugin I'm not aware of to help create Tilemaps inside Unity?

I want, for example, 1 tile of grass to be able to react if I hit it with a hoe, or water, and change to dirt. Is my only option to create prefabs and place every tile as its own gameobject? won't that kill performance in a large world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try exporting your Tiled tilemap to .tmx format, creating a script in Unity that loads .tmx files for your map and reads every single tile in a for loop.

You would need to assign a prefab to each tile ID of your tilemap, and in that prefab you could have your script with logic attached (grass reacting to a hoe/water) and graphics.

Other idea is to export one big image of your map, and then export .tmx format in the same way as explained before but create game objects only for ID's that player can interact with and only attach scripts to them.